# Unable to install python mysqlclient on windows

Tags: mysql, django

This is the error I get when I try installing mysqlclient. I am using Windows and python 3.5. I tried all the methods given on the stackoverflow but still nothing.

```
Installing 'mysqlclient'
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.6.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient
    Complete output from command "c:\users\buccaneer\documents\visual studio            2013\Projects\del1\del1\envrm\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\BUCCAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-wuhkxhu3\\mysqlclient\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\BUCCAN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3jbluuk2-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "c:\users\buccaneer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\del1\del1\envrm\include\site\python3.5\mysqlclient":
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.5
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.5\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: maybe dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: @Shine No its not dup. There seems to be issue with mysqlclient in python3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) currently says that it supports Python 2.7, 3.3-3.4.

I would try with Python 3.4. Python 3.5 has only recently been released.

If it works on 3.4 but not 3.5, you could [open an issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) on the project's GitHub page.

Comment: Yup.. Its seems to be working with p3.4 but not with 3.5. Thanks. :)

Comment: For future reference, the OP opened [this issue](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/54).